# Is there a way to tell one browser instance from another when running concurrent tests in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there a way to tell one browser instance from another when running concurrent tests in Testcafe?

Say we have two tests.

- One creates some entity and then changes it and verifies that change is applied correctly.
- Another deletes all the entities and verifies that everything is deleted.

If we run these tests in parallel they will interfere with each other. So there must be either a way to embrace this concurrency and synchronize these tests with some primitive or to make them parallel and run in isolated sandboxes.

I would prefer to go to the second option.
It could be something like

```js
test('Some test', async t => {
  await useSandbox(t.browser.alias, t.browser.os.name, t.browser.instanceId);
  ... rest of the test
})
```

But AFAIK there is no way to tell one browser instance from another inside the test code. Or is there?

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe does not have a mechanism to affect test execution from another test. When TestCafe starts tests in parallel, it does not suppose that one test will interfere another.

TestCafe starts every test with clear cookies, storages and a user profile. So, if your data is kept in localStorage, every test will be run independently. However, if your data is kept on the server side (i.e. in a database), then TestCafe cannot use it in a sandbox, since all tests interact with DB through the same website.

In this case, it's better to run these two tests one by one, not simultaneously.

Comment: Yes our tests concurrently use the same server-side data.

Comment: We could isolate server side data for one thread from another, but to do so we need to know which browser instance are we in now. We could also more or less make that isolation on per-test basis. But I like the option with per thread isolation better.

Comment: @mixture, TestCafe does not have the functionality to identify a browser instance in which the test is run. I would suggest you use the per-test isolation you mentioned.

Comment: It seems to be an easy-to-add functionality. Should I post a feature request or is it not as simple as I think?

Comment: @mixture, Yes, feel free to create an issue in [our GitHub repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues)